# How to control the maximum value of variables?

Tags: c#, int, global-variables, console-application

As the title says, I would like to set the maximum value of the skill, stam and luck integers to the value of the related *Max integers. The *Max int values are set randomly during the start up of the program and the regular values are changed throughout the running of the program. There may be a few instances where the *Max value gets increased or decreased during play.

```
public static int skillMax = 0;
public static int stamMax = 0;
public static int luckMax = 0;
public static int skill = skillMax;
public static int stam = stamMax;
public static int luck = luckMax;
```

As my knowledge of C# is still in its infancy, I have not tried much. However I have searched far and wide on the internet however and not been able to find anything except for the MinValue and MaxValue fields and this piece of code with no explanation:

```
protected int m_cans;

public int Cans
{
    get { return m_cans; }
    set {
        m_cans = Math.Min(value, 10);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you throw my way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation for the code: `Cans` is a property. Properties provide controlled access to  class or struct fields (variables). They consist of two methods called `get` to return a value and `set` to assign the value. A property can also have only a getter or only a setter.

The property `Cans` stores its value in a so called backing field. Here `m_cans`. The setter gets the new value through the keyword `value`.

`Math.Min(value, 10)` returns the minimum of the two parameters. I.e., for example, if `value` is 8, then 8 is assigned to `m_cans`. If `value` is 12, then 10 is assigned to `m_cans`.

You can use this property like this

```
var obj = new MyCalss(); // Replace by your real class or struct name.
obj.Cans = 20; // Calls the setter with `value` = 20.
int x = obj.Cans; // Calls the getter and returns 10;
```

Properties help to implement the principle of [Information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding).

---

You can easily adapt this example your variables. Often class level variables (fields) are prepended with `_` to differentiate them from local variables, i.e. variables declared in methods. Properties are written in PascalCase.

```
private static int _skillMax; // Fields are automatically initialized to the default
                              // value of their type. For `int` this is `0`.
public static int SkillMax
{
    get { return _skillMax; }
    set {
        _skillMax = value;
        _skill = _skillMax; // Automatically initializes the initial value of Skill.
                            // At program start up you only need to set `SkillMax`.
    }
}

private static int _skill;
public static int Skill
{
    get { return _skill; }
    set { _skill = Math.Min(value, _skillMax); }
}
```

Comment: Took me a moment to understand how to implement it correctly. But once I did, it has worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Create methods to update values

```
private static void UpdateSkill(int newValue)
{
  skill = newValue;
  skillMax = newValue > skillMax ? newValue : skillMax;
}
```